# LaTeXTools + Sublime + Windows + TEXINPUTS

Tags: xetex, windows, sublime-text, latextools, texinputs

Can't find the way how to fix problem with TEXINPUTS env.

In my docs I use personal .sty templates. Every doc is a new `git` repository.

Usually I put my template to `texlive\texmf-dist\tex\latex\mytemp`
and use it by `\usepackage{mytemp}` command in `doc.tex` file.

Now I decided to create repository for my `mytemp` package and use it as submodule in new documents.

So document working dir is:

- mytemp\mytemp.sty
- mytemp\mytemp1.sty (dependency for mytemp.sty)
- doc.tex
- .gitmodules

On windows 7 with Sublime Text 3 build gets an error: `LaTeX Error: File mytemp.sty not found`

I want to use relative path to my package and tried to edit LaTeXTools setting:

```
"builder_settings" : {
    "windows" : {
        "env" : {
            "TEXINPUTS" : ".:$TEXINPUTS"    
        }
    }
}
```

But error still not fixed.

Any thought how to fix it?

I've tried lots of variants, but still no result.

PS. On MacOS everything builds ok even without redefining `TEXINPUTS` in LaTeXTools settings.

Answer (score 1):

For path variables on posix/unix/mac where you see : (colon) **on Windows it is ;** (semicolon)

For this disparity you need to go back long time in history and blame the system manufacturers not coming to a concordant method i.e. going back to CP/M using : as a drive to path separator taken forward through IBM /MS DOS ant thus into Windows. so windows will accept / in lieu of \ but will not accept : inlieu of ;

thus try  variants on the following which are probably NOT all correct note the first ENV separator after Texinputs" is still:

"TEXINPUTS": ".//;q:/hard coded/location/;./my sub dirs/;$TEXINPUTS;"

Notes
There should be NO full colons : inside a windows path unless it is an absolute address for a drive e.g "D:/mydata"  and .:/whatever is NOT valid.

.// should translate to current and various subdirs from there
A:/whatever/ is an absolute path and should be terminated/
./my sub/ is a relative subdirectory in space and not recommended
$TEXINPUTS roughly = ; and unlikely to work as the end now translates to ;;;
so for this variable avoid $TEXINPUTS OR %TEXINPUTS% just ensure the last character inside the final" on the line is ; thus end the line with ;"

Comment: I've already tried to use semicolon ;
`"TEXINPUTS": ".//:q;./mytemp/;$TEXINPUTS;"`
or
`"TEXINPUTS": ".//:./mytemp/;$TEXINPUTS;"`

Both variants causes xelatex.exe crush

Comment: both the examples you show have posix separators between the second quotes no such drive as ".:" = crash

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me a lot!